# SwiftData append items to array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to simply append date items to an array of dates but I get the error:
**No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Item {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var item: String
    var date: Date
    
    init(id: String, item: String, date: Date = .now) {
        self.id = id
        self.item = item
        self.date = date
    }
    
}
```

And here's where I try to create the array:

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var allItems: [Item]        
            
    @State private var itemDates: [Date] = []

    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(allItems) { item in
            itemDates.append(item.date)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error, is because you have procedural code `itemDates.append(item.date)` in the `ForEach`.

The `ForEach` loop in the body is not the "normal" for loop, it is a View that must return other Views.

Use this approach to append to your `itemDates`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var allItems: [Item]
    @State private var itemDates: [Date] = []  // <-- is it really needed?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 33) {
            Text("itemDates.count: \(itemDates.count)")
            ForEach(allItems) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(item.item)")
                    Text("at: \(item.date, format: .dateTime)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // here, setup the data
            allItems.forEach {    // <--- note the small `f`
                itemDates.append($0.date)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can simply not use `itemDates` and use `allItems` directly.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var allItems: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 33) {
            Text("allItems.count: \(allItems.count)")
            ForEach(allItems) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(item.item)")
                    Text("at: \(item.date, format: .dateTime)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the body property within a View struct is responsible for defining the view's content and layout, and it is not intended for making changes to the data.

For example you can do this inside **var body: some View {}**

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        allItems.forEach { item in
            itemDates.append(item.date)
        }
    }) {
        Text("Add Date")
    }
}
```